# Firebase init is not create a default project its stop by saying a title project setup

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-tools

I am new to firebase.

I am trying to use firebase cloud function for my project.

I have installed npm and nodejs on my windows machine and then I login my firebase account using:

```
firebase login
```

Then I created a folder where I want my scripts to be. i've gone to that path in cmd and try to run:

```
firebase init
```

It as an alert are you ready to proceed I given `y`.

Then it blinking till here which I have attached in my image

[image]

Can anyone help me out what to do?

Comment: What happens if you run `firebase list`? Can you run with `--debug` and paste in the last few lines where it gets stuck?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I tried that it saying to run firebase init first

Comment: `firebase list` does not have an error message about running `firebase init` first. Please copy and paste the actual error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do it select one of the options: 
 - Database
 - Functions
 - Hosting

I'm using a linux (see below) so all I have to do is press enter. I don't know about Windows, but I think its expecting you to enter some response.

[image]